# Selenium ChromeDriver: increasing time of getting WebElement Text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code in which I traverse table rows and columns, and I'd like to add it's values to a list.

It takes me a significant amount of time.

So I added a time measurement, and I noticed that for some reason the time increases from row to row.

I cannot understand why.

Can you advise please?

```
private void buildTableDataMap() {

    WebElement table = chromeWebDriver.findElement(By.id("table-type-1"));

    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    theMap.getInstance().clear();

    String item;
    for (WebElement row : rows) {

        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>(); 

        List<WebElement> tds = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        if(tds.size() > 0){

            WebElement last = tds.get(tds.size() - 1);

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            values.addAll(tds.stream().map(e->e.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            //remove redundant last entry:
            values.remove(tds.size() - 1);
            callSomeFunc(values, last);

            item = tds.get(TABLE_COLUMNS.NAME_COL.getNumVal()).getText();
            item = item.replaceAll("[^.\\- /'&A-Za-z0-9]", "").trim();//remove redundant chars

            theMap.getInstance().getMap().put(item, values);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Guys, I continued researching.
First of all, Florent's kind answer did not help me because, at lease as I understand, It returned me an array list of strings which I had to parse, and I don't like this kind of solution too much...

So I nailed the problem in finding that the **e.getText()** call was increasing in time from call to call!!!
I also tried **e.getAttribute("innerText")** instead but no change.
Can't understand why. Any idea to solve?

```
            WebElement last = null;
            for (WebElement e : tds){
                last = e;

                long tm1 = 0, tm2 = 0;
                if(Settings.verboseYN) {
                    tm1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                s = e.getText(); //This action increases in time!!!
                if(Settings.verboseYN) {
                    tm2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                values.add(s); //a 0 ms action!!!
                if(Settings.verboseYN) {
                    System.out.println("e.getText()) took " + (tm2 - tm1) + " ms...");
                }
            }
```

That is an graph of the time getText took...

[image]

---

08-May-18
Another source of growing execution time is this one:

```
void func(WebElement anchorsElement){

    List<WebElement> anchors = anchorsElement.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement a : anchors) {

        if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("a") > 0)
            values.add("A");
        else if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("b") > 0)
            values.add("B");
        else if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("c") > 0)
            values.add("C");

    }
}
```

Every functions has 5 iterations only, but still each call to the function increases its execution time.
Is there a solution for this one as well?

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: @DebanjanB There are no specific manual steps. What I am trying to do is to extract data from some site tables. All the tables has the same structure.

Comment: did you find that if website itself taking time to return data or selenium code is responsible for that?

Comment: @HelpingHands I am not sure whether the issue is in the site, the selenium infrastructure or simply java. Notice that I merely measure the timing of: values.addAll(tds.stream().map(e->e.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList())); and it is the one which increases constantly from measurement to measurement. Maybe it is logical and depends on the initial values list size?

Comment: @dushkin - how many total rows there in page with which you trying to interact and store into array?

Comment: @HelpingHands It varies... Iam talking about an average of 400 cells. For example a table of 25 rows on 10 columns more or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of the way Selenium works by design. Let's look at how a JavaScript get's executed or a operation is performed

```
tds.get(TABLE_COLUMNS.NAME_COL.getNumVal()).getText();
```

You have a collection of objects. Each object is assigned a unique ID on the browser side by the selenium driver

So when you do a `getText()` below is what happens

```
Your code -> HTTP Request -> Browser Driver -> Browser ->
                                                        |
           <---------------------------------------------
```

Now if you have a table of 400rx10c then it accounts to `4000` HTTP calls, even if one call takes 10ms, we are looking at a `40000ms~=40sec`, which is a decent delay to read a table

So what you want to do is to get all the data in single go by executing a javascript which give you 2d array back. It is quite simple, I found a code on below site

http://cwestblog.com/2016/08/21/javascript-snippet-convert-html-table-to-2d-array/

```
function tableToArray(tbl, opt_cellValueGetter) {
  opt_cellValueGetter = opt_cellValueGetter || function(td) { return td.textContent || td.innerText; };
  var twoD = [];
  for (var rowCount = tbl.rows.length, rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
    twoD.push([]);
  }
  for (var rowIndex = 0, tr; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
    var tr = tbl.rows[rowIndex];
    for (var colIndex = 0, colCount = tr.cells.length, offset = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++) {
      var td = tr.cells[colIndex], text = opt_cellValueGetter(td, colIndex, rowIndex, tbl);
      while (twoD[rowIndex].hasOwnProperty(colIndex + offset)) {
        offset++;
      }
      for (var i = 0, colSpan = parseInt(td.colSpan, 10) || 1; i < colSpan; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, rowSpan = parseInt(td.rowSpan, 10) || 1; j < rowSpan; j++) {
          twoD[rowIndex + j][colIndex + offset + i] = text;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return twoD;
}
```

I assume you store the above script in a `SCRIPT` variable and then you can run it like below

```
WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)table).getWrappedDriver();
Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(SCRIPT + "\n return tableToArray(arguments[0]);" , table);
```

This will get you a 2D array of the data and you can then process it the way you like it

Comment: Tarun, thank you for your well explained answer. Isn't your solution a variation of Florent's solution? To return a string ArrayList of the table? The problem I had with Florent's solution is that for some reason the last WebElement in the row was not given in the output of his function. So, I could extract its value only using element.getText(). I'm afraid I will have the same problem here as well, but I will try it anyway.

Comment: @dushkin, Yes its on the same lines only, if you are not getting the last row then there could be two reasons behind the same. The last last row is not part of the main table or there its something which is nested inside the same table. Also I wanted to add the explanation on the time delays you asked for. If this doesn't work then provide the HTML of the table for us to inspect

Comment: I may have didn't explain myself well. I am not getting the last td value in the row. I will give a try and update soon

Answer (score 6):

Calling the driver is an expensive operation. To significantly reduce the execution time, use a JavaScript injection with `executeScript` to read the whole table in a single call. Then process/filter the data on the client side with Java.

```
public ArrayList<?> readTable(WebElement table)
{
    final String JS_READ_CELLS = 
        "var table = arguments[0]; " +
        "return map(table.querySelectorAll('tr'), readRow); " +
        "function readRow(row) { return map(row.querySelectorAll('td'), readCell) }; " +
        "function readCell(cell) { return cell.innerText }; " +
        "function map(items, fn) { return Array.prototype.map.call(items, fn) }; " ;

    WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)table).getWrappedDriver();
    Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(JS_READ_CELLS, table);
    return (ArrayList<?>)result;
}
```

Comment: I see the table being read, but when trying to return it casted to Object[], I get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: I initially wrote it for C#, so the returned type might be different. FYI, the script returns a jagged array. Try casting the Object to an `(ArrayList<?>)result`.

Comment: I really thank you for your effort. Please look amendment to question. Thanks