# Selenium ChromeDriver: increasing time of getting Anchor element value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is actually a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097877/selenium-chromedriver-increasing-time-of-getting-webelement-text), but since the question was quite long, and an answer was given already for a bounty, I am afraid it won't get any attention there, even though I added it to the end of the text.
So, managers - I hope you will decide the best decision for giving this question the proper publication - here or still in the previous question.

This time, I have an increasing time when looping on anchor elements. 
That is, every call the func() takes more time.
The loop has 5 iterations only.

```
void func(WebElement anchorsElement){

    List<WebElement> anchors = anchorsElement.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement a : anchors) {

        if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("a") > 0)
            values.add("A");
        else if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("b") > 0)
            values.add("B");
        else if (a.getAttribute("class").indexOf("c") > 0)
            values.add("C");

    }
}
```

This time, I am not interested in text but I need to get the class names. That is why I couldn't use the solution given to me on the previous question.

This is an example of the anchors element:

```
<div class="meetings-8 ">
    <a class="Call-bg Call-s glib-tvene-dW1eVj25 glib-thepart-WdKOwxDM-Wtn9Stg0 glib-partnames-alal;Ashkelon" title="[b]Next meeting:[/b]
alal - Ashkelon
13.05.2018">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="Call-bg a glib-tvene-j1TJiPdn glib-thepart-Wtn9Stg0-2XrRecc3 glib-partnames-Ashkelon;kdkdkdkd" title="[b]991818&amp;nbsp;[/b](Ashkelon - kdkdkdkd)
09.05.2018">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="Call-bg b glib-tvene-lhJEIDIa glib-thepart-Wtn9Stg0-xxxpBZl2 glib-partnames-Ashkelon;ieieie" title="[b]920032&amp;nbsp;[/b](Ashkelon - ieieie)
06.05.2018">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="Call-bg a glib-tvene-IBZf2hYI glib-thepart-Cxq57r8g-Wtn9Stg0 glib-partnames-west-ham;Ashkelon" title="[b]882772&amp;nbsp;[/b](mcmcmcmc - Ashkelon)
29.04.2018">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="Call-bg a glib-tvene-0U3juSVT glib-thepart-Wtn9Stg0-K6xezbY7 glib-partnames-Ashkelon;kKkssks" title="[b]001991&amp;nbsp;[/b](Ashkelon - kKkssks)
22.04.2018">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="Call-bg Call-bg-last a glib-tvene-ddkDE7Ld glib-thepart-UDg08Ohm-Wtn9Stg0 glib-partnames-kokok;Ashkelon" title="[b]722726&amp;nbsp;[/b](kokok - Ashkelon)
14.04.2018">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Can you assist please?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you looking for a specific class that's applied, or just a letter in the applied CSS classes? For example, are you looking for the "b" or "big" in `class="big brown boxes"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like your previous question, you can execute JavaScript on the webpage to make fewer calls over the wire:

```
var parent = arguments[0];
// ^ JavaScript is executed as a function call.
//   We need to get the parent element passed as an argument.

Array.from(parent.getElementsByTagName('a'))
//         ^ Get all the "a" tags in the parent
// ^ and convert the HTMLCollection to an Array so we can use reduce
.reduce(
// ^ Reduce will call the following callback on each element with an "accumulated" value (your result) and the current element of the array. The first value of the accumulator is the initial value we provide as the second argument
  (acc, anchor) => {
    if (anchor.classList.contains("a")) {
    //        ^ The classList.contains method will check if the anchor has the class "a" applied.
      acc.push("A");
      // ^ Add "A" to the accumulator
    }
    if (anchor.classList.contains("b")) { acc.push("B"); }
    if (anchor.classList.contains("c")) { acc.push("C"); }
    return acc;
    // ^ Return the accumulated value for the next iteration
  },
  [],
  // ^ Initial value of the accumulator
);
```

Simplified, the JavaScript is:

```
Array.from(arguments[0].getElementsByTagName('a'))
  .reduce((acc, { classList }) => {
    classList.contains("a") && acc.push("A");
    classList.contains("b") && acc.push("B");
    classList.contains("c") && acc.push("C");
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Which you can wrap in a call like your previous question:

```
public ArrayList<?> func(WebElement element)
{
    final String JS_TRANSFORM_ANCHOR_CLASSES_TO_VALUES = 
        "return Array.from(arguments[0].getElementsByTagName('a'))\n" +
        "  .reduce((acc, { classList }) => {\n"
        "    classList.contains(\"a\") && acc.push(\"A\");\n"
        "    classList.contains(\"b\") && acc.push(\"B\");\n"
        "    classList.contains(\"c\") && acc.push(\"C\");\n"
        "    return acc;\n"
        "  }, []);\n"

    WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)table).getWrappedDriver();
    Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(JS_TRANSFORM_ANCHOR_CLASSES_TO_VALUES, element);
    return (ArrayList<?>)result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I am getting result as null. Two more information points:  1. "a", "b" and "c" are partial strings of the class attribute value. Meaning the class value is something like: "xx x a xx xxxx". Does the code above supports that? 2. Instead of writing "contains("a")" I had to change it to  "contains(\"a\")" to succeed compiling the code.

Comment: I've added an example of the anchors element to the main post

Comment: With all the explanation I'm surprised you didn't try it in the browser. It works fine: https://jsbin.com/lafapes/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Your explanation was perfect. Thank you. I will debug my code to see what went wrong..

Comment: It was likely just the missing `return` statement.

Comment: YES YES YES! Wondering why I decided probably automatically, without noticing, to remove the return statement :(   Thanks again!